# Recorrer Array de Array json con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

tengo una función de cakephp que me devuelve datos en formato json de la siguiente manera

```
 $response = array($query_license,$query_estate,$result_license);
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        echo json_encode($response);
        die();
    }
```

Bien para poder recuperar los datos hago lo siguiente

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            url: license,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{id_user_license:id_user_license,id_evaluation:id_evaluation},
            success: function (data){
                $.each(data,function(i,s){
                    if(s[0].cantidad_pendiente === 0){
                        $("#message_license").html('<p>Usted no cuenta con licensias disponibles</p>');
                        $("#modal_report__footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>');
                    }else if(s[0].estado === 3){
                        $("#message_license").html('<p>Usted cuenta con '+ s[0].cantidad_pendiente +'</p>');
                        $("#message_consumed").html('<p>Esta evaluacion ya consumio licencia</p>');
                        $("#modal_report__footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>');
                    }else{
                        $("#message_license").html('<p>Usted cuenta con '+ s.indexOf(3).cantidad_pendiente +'</p>');
                        $("#modal_report__footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Consumir</button>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

El problema esta que cuando recupero los valores para mostrarlos al usuario me muestra **undefined** y verificando dentro de la consola veo esto

```
console.log(s[0].cantidad_pendiente);
5
undefined
```

para verificar que estan llegando los datos en el objeto data realice `console.log(data);`

y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

por algún motivo me trae el valor y luego muestra vació algo estoy haciendo mal o tengo que cambiar gracias por su ayuda

Comment: Por favor coloca un ejemplo de la respuesta JSON que obtienes. El `undefined` es porque (o le estás apuntando a una propiedad que no existe) o esta propiedad no tiene datos.

Comment: esto me trae cuando reviso el data asi: `console.log(data);` la respuesta es esta `Array[2]
0
:
Array[1]
0
:
Object
cantidad_pendiente
:
5
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]
1
:
Array[1]
0
:
Object
estado
:
3
__proto__
:
Object
length
:
1
__proto__
:
Array[0]
length
:
2
__proto__
:
Array[0]`

Comment: Gracias por la recomendación bueno probe y me muestra esto  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'cantidad_pendiente' of undefined`

Comment: Por favor haz la siguiente prueba: oprime la tecla F12 y selecciona la pestaña "console", luego ejecuta tu código. A continuación, expande cada propiedad del objeto `data` y toma una captura de pantalla del resultado de `console.log(data);`. luego **edita tu pregunta** seleccionando el enlace "editar" - que se encuentra debajo de tu pregunta; luego, pulsa sobre el icono en forma de imagen que se encuentra en las herramientas de edición.

Comment: Ya esta modifique la pregunta con lo que mencionaste :)

Comment: Creo que no tienes que cambiar nada :) el `undefined` en la consola no es un error, esto pasa cada vez que usas `console.log();` en tu consola prueba esta línea: `console.log('hola mundo');` y lo verás.

Comment: me lo muestra asi `2 Hola mundo`, eso es dentro del each estoy el console.log('hola mundo')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que el problema radica en PHP y es que estas devolviendo un array asociativo en JSON sin definirlo en PHP.

Intenta cambiar

Esto

```
echo json_encode($response);
```

Por esto

```
echo json_encode($response, true);
```

El argumento que agregamos es "assoc", por defecto esta en false a menos que lo definas como true. Podes leer mas acerca de esta funcion en http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php.

Comment: Ya esta formule una nueva pregunta aquí http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/45160/recuperar-valor-de-un-array-de-array-json-con-jquery ayuda por favor