# Recuperar valor de un array de array json con jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Tengo los siguientes datos que son devueltos en json para recuperar los con jquery

```
$response = array($query_license,$query_estate);
    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {
        echo json_encode($response,TRUE);
        die();
    }
```

esta es la respuesta del json en codigo php

```
[[{"cantidad_pendiente":5}],[{"estado":3}]]
```

mi función para recuperar los datos del json

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            url: license,
            dataType: 'json',
            data:{id_user_license:id_user_license,id_evaluation:id_evaluation},
            success: function (data){
                $.each(data,function(i,s){
                    console.log(s);
                    if(s[0].cantidad_pendiente === 0){
                        $("#message_license").html('<p>Usted no cuenta con licensias disponibles</p>');
                        $("#modal_report__footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>');
                    }else if(s[0].estado === 3){
                        $("#message_license").html('<p>Usted cuenta con '+ s[0].cantidad_pendiente +'</p>');
                        $("#message_consumed").html('<p>Esta evaluacion ya consumio licencia</p>');
                        $("#modal_report__footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>');
                    }else{
                        $("#message_license").html('<p>Usted cuenta con '+ s[0].cantidad_pendiente +'</p>');
                        $("#modal_report__footer").html('<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger">Consumir</button>');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

ahora verifique los datos con `console.log(data);` esto fue el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ahora cuando lo hago los mismo pero dentro del each

```
$.each(data,function(i,s){
          console.log(s)
 }
```

me resulta esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

ahora mi duda es como me posiciono en cantidad_pendiente y mostrar su valor al usuario, porque haciéndolo asi `$("#message_license").html('<p>Usted cuenta con '+ s[0].cantidad_pendiente +'</p>');`  dentro de mi if me muestra **undefined** tal vez estoy haciendo mal :(

Comment: Podrias por favor agregar a tu pregunta el codigo JSON que estas procesando?. Quisiera ver el texto literal que esta devolviendo esta sentencia "echo json_encode($response,TRUE)" para poder armarte un ejemplo especifico

Comment: Pues mira esto es lo que me muestra `[[{"cantidad_pendiente":5}],[{"estado":3}]]` el json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema radica en que tu array JSON esta mal formado pero te proveo un parche para que puedas trabajar sin alterar tu JSON.

```
data = [[{"cantidad_pendiente":5}],[{"estado":3}]];
$.each(data,function(i,s){
    if (data[i][Object.keys(data[i])].cantidad_pendiente){
        console.log("Cantidad pendiente: "+data[i][Object.keys(data[i])].cantidad_pendiente);
    }
    if (data[i][Object.keys(data[i])].estado){
        console.log("Estado: "+data[i][Object.keys(data[i])].estado);
    }
});
```

Con estas validaciones generales tendrias que poder idendificar si estas procesando ESTADO o CANTIDAD PENDIENTE para ejecutar la rutina que necesites.

Desconozco como estes formando este array pero no es posible acceder al indice mediante el key que interpreta la consola, es por esto que utilizo el prototipo Object.keys() para recuperar el KEY del ultimo nivel de cada array. Cabe aclarar que esta solucion solo es valida por que el ultimo nivel de tu array solo tiene un KEY.

Te dejo un ejemplo a modo de prueba de concepto:
https://jsfiddle.net/12ubqodq/

Comment: Por favor, si esta respuesta tanto como la que te di en la pregunta anterior te ayudaron, considera calificar ambas respuestas.

Comment: Muchas Gracias ya entendí a lo que te refieres me ayudo bastante